# List scrolling on extjs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using extjs 6 for my project earlier we were having Sencha touch. We have  recently migrated our codebase from touch to extjs modern.

I am facing an issue with list element. With Sencha touch list there was a scrollable container and then scroller, but in extjs scrollable container is removed and now in extjs 6 list scrollable itself is scroller element. This scroller element only appears when list has n numbers of rows, where n * list-item-height > list-height.

My problem is if we are having pull refresh control and list has very few element (say <5) then i am not able to scroll list. How to scroll container in that case so pull refresh can be visible. In this scenario pull refresh part is fully broken.

To see problem, just run following example in sencha fiddle. 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-modern/Ext.plugin.PullRefresh.html

Pull refresh is never visible until you add more items till it fill the list.

Let me know if more detail is needed.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Manish Kumar

Comment: You should either set scrollable or container. With less items the list not meant to be scrollable.

Comment: @ProtoBassi thanks for your comment. Let's consider a case where we are showing contacts from the server on your mobile device. After some time someone added few more contact to list on the server. To refresh the list we use pull refresh (on mobile). 

So now if container is not scrollable, you cannot invoke pull refresh. 

got it?

BTW I got the solution, it requires list's scrollable to be 'scroll'
scrollable : {
y : 'scroll',
x: 'auto'
}